# Unable to delete IMAP mail account in Yosemite

Tags: macos, mail.app, system-settings

I have an IMAP mail account in the Apple Mail client that I want to delete.  I first goto the Accounts preferences pane in Mail.  When I click the minus icon to delete the account, I get a message about having to do it in Internet Accounts.

[image]

However, when I goto Internet Accounts, the email account isn't listed.  I see all of my mail accounts except for this particular one.

How can I delete this mail account?

Comment: ok, so what kind of mail is it (from whom)? your Yosemite says it is in Internet Accounts ?

Comment: A custom domain with Windows Live email (now through Outlook.com).  It's not an actual @outlook.com email, rather using that service with a custom domain.

Comment: It is listed on the Accounts pane of the Mail settings, but not in Internet Accounts.  Very weird.  Also, I do have other accounts with the same type of service (custom domain from Outlook) that show up fine.

Comment: How did you install it in first place ?

Comment: Does it show the "Enable this Account" checked in Mail accounts? You must had set it up manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is not my Fix I found it [here](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/Where_Mac_OS_X_Mail_Stores_Mail.htm)

Find and Open the Folder Where Mac OS X Mail Stores Mail. To open the folder where Mac OS X Mail keeps your messages:

1. Open a Finder window.
2. Select Go | Go to Folder… from the menu.
3. Type `~/Library/Mail/V2`

Delete all the folders and files in this directory

Find and Open the Folder Where Mac OS X Mail Store Mail. To locate the folder where Mac OS X Mail stores mail:

1. Open a Finder window.
2. Select Go | Go to Folder… from the menu.
3. Type `~/Library/Mail/`

Delete the folders. Now all the Accounts will get deleted from mail